# Django/Python POST data from form (without using models) to MySQL db

Tags: python, mysql, django, forms

I'm trying to insert data from a template form to MySQL database but it's not working.

The form:

```
class AddPollForm(forms.Form):
    poll_time = forms.CharField(label='Tiempo Poll', max_length=10) 
    poll_ip = forms.CharField(label='IP', max_length=50) 
    communitydata = forms.CharField(label='Community Data', max_length=100)
    snmp_oid = forms.CharField(label='OID', max_length=250)
    lastcheck = forms.CharField(label='Última Comprobación', max_length=20)
```

My form in the template:

```
<form action="/services/listpolls/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" id="add" value="Añadir">
</form>
```

The views:

```
@csrf_exempt
def listpolls(request):
    connect_mysql = mdb.connect('****', '***', '***', 'noname_jc_sandbox')
    cursorMYSQL = connect_mysql.cursor(mdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    query = "select id,ip,polling_time,communitydata,snmp_oid,lastcheck from snmptt_listpolls order by ip desc limit 100"
    cursorMYSQL.execute(query)
    b = cursorMYSQL.fetchall()
    connect_mysql.close()

    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = AddPollForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():

            poll_time = form.cleaned_data['poll_time']
            ip = form.cleaned_data['poll_ip']

            connect_mysql = mdb.connect('***', '***', '***', 'noname_jc_sandbox')
            cursorMYSQL = connect_mysql.cursor(mdb.cursors.DictCursor)
            cursorMYSQL.execute("insert into snmptt_listpolls (ip, polling_time) values (34, 34)")

            connect_mysql.commit()
            connect_mysql.close()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('listpolls.html')

        else:
            form = AddPollForm()
            return render_to_response("listpolls.html",{"buffer_data": b, 'form': form} )        

    else:
        form = AddPollForm()
        return render_to_response("listpolls.html",{"buffer_data": b, 'form': form} )
```

Here we get the data from the db and show it in a table, which works fine. I also have the form and when I press add I want to add another row to the db.

The type of the fields are:

```
| id            | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| ip            | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| polling_time  | int(10)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| communitydata | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| snmp_oid      | varchar(250) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| lastcheck     | datetime
```

Comment: Saying 'it isn't working' isn't very helpful. Which part isn't working? If you remove the `form = AddPollForm()` from the else statement when the form is not valid, then the template should display any form errors.

Comment: If you are going to manually generate each and every query there's no point in using django, you can leave it out! Even if you want to run the occasional raw sql you can still use the raw() method in the manager.

Comment: I made both of Alasdair and e4c5's points in this user's previous question. Unfortunately it is very unclear what she is trying to do.

Comment: Plus, it is worse than previously implied, as you are now opening and closing the db connection twice in a single view. This is, not to put too fine a point on it, nonsense.

Comment: Why can't you use django ORM here? You can define multiple databases in settings and create models with `managed=False` which mean that django won't touch structure of table corresponding to model.

Comment: @Alasdair I didn't notice that line and removing it helped me solve the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @DanielRoseman About opening and closing the db connection, yes, I need to refactor the code and clean it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, this is the line I needed but I couldn't manage to get there and also I didn't know how to explain myself better. Anyway, I found my answer and, just in case, here it is:

```
cursorMYSQL.execute("""insert into snmptt_listpolls (ip, polling_time, communitydata, snmp_oid) values ('%s','%s','%s','%s')"""%(ip, poll_time, communitydata, snmp_oid))
```